# SQL Server ISNULL and Entity Framework stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, isnull

I have a SQL Server DB that my MVC app has access to via Entity Framework 6. I have a stored proc that does some totals and stores it in a temp table, then returns the results via a final select statement (simplified version):

```
select isnull(TotalDataShared, 0) as TotalDataShared from #main;
```

There are cases that TotalDataShared can be null, so I have to check for it. The auto-generated EF entity for the proc result looks like this (also simplified):

```
public partial class getUsageTotals_Result
{
    public decimal TotalDataShared { get; set; }
}
```

My repo method calls the proc like this:

```
    public UsageTotals GetCurrentUsage(int accountId)
    {
        var ret = _context.getUsageTotals(accountId).First();

        return new UsageTotals {
            DataShared = (double)ret.TotalDataShared
        };
    }
```

When TotalDataShared in #main is not null everything works fine. When It's null, I get the following error in my app:

> The 'TotalDataShared' property on 'getUsageTotals_Result' could not be
>   set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a
>   non-null value of type 'System.Decimal'.

It seems to me that it's ignoring the ISNULL command. I've tried wrapping the last select in a table var since I've had issues in the past returning data from temp tables before in EF, but doesn't do any good.

I've also tried using COALESCE() and it gives the same results. I've also tried removing and recreating the object in EF, to no avail. I've also tried returning a non-zero float value if it's null (ISNULL(TotalDataShared, 4.441)) but that doesn't change anything either.

Not sure what to try next. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Adding stored proc skeleton:

```
create proc getUsageTotals @accountid int
as

if object_id('tempdb..#main') is not null drop table #main;
create table #main (    

    TotalDataShared float,
)

. . .
. . .

select isnull(TotalDataShared, 4.441) as TotalDataShared from #main;

go
```

The final two lines of the proc are the select and "go", so the return value should be the select statement, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you show the procedure code?

Comment: I added the sproc skeleton. It's a simple proc, with normal inner joins to get totals and inserting it into a temp table. Then, the final select is shown.

Comment: `isnull` returns the datatype of the first parameter. This is `float` that maps to `double` in `C#`. Why have you defined it as `decimal`? Is there any conditional logic in the procedure? Or was the metadata inferred from an earlier version of the proc?

Comment: Yes, I initially matched it to the first version of the proc. But it's been several iterations now, and it all has worked fine, without me having to change anything on my end, until the NULLs issue appeared.

Comment: Your analysis is not correct as the fact that there was a null removed by `isnull` is completely opaque to calling code. It doesn't affect the datatype returned and EF has no way of knowing that. You will probably find that you get the error on all calls now. Either change the temp table column definition to `TotalDataShared decimal(x,y)` or redo the metadata discovery to expect a float/double.

Comment: That's the weird thing. When there is data in the table, the code works fine. even if I do "select 4.441;" it works fine. That's why I say it has to do with the ISNULL.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I did, however, change the select statement to select from the original table and regenerate the types on the EF side, and that worked! This came from your suggestion to change the temp table types to match. If you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: if the issue is when no rows are returned at all then `Isnull` has no effect and SQL Server will return an empty result. I don't know EF well enough to know if that will cause problems. Does it always expect a scalar single row result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- In your Entity Framework model (open the .edmx file), right-click on
  the diagram background and select Model Browser.
- Open the Complex Types tree.
- Open your stored procedure, maybe called getUsageTotals_Result.
- Right-click on the TotalDataShared line and select Properties.
- Change Nullable to true.

I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, the procedure returns 0 rows if there are no results in the `#main` table. So `_context.getUsageTotals(accountId)` may return zero rows, and you can easily tackle that by:

```
var ret = _context.getUsageTotals(accountId)
                  .FirstOrDefault(); // FirstOrDefault!

return new UsageTotals {
    DataShared = (double)(ret == null ? 0 : ret.TotalDataShared);
};
```